# how to disable the x axis and y axis line in google api line chart

Tags: google-api, linechart

im using google api for line graph in my web application. in that line chart i dont want x axis line and y axis line, but i cant to fine how to remove the lines except the graph. could you please help me. i used [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) example for my practice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you cant remove or disable your x and y axis in google api the alter way is to set the baselineColor and gridlineColor same as the background color and set the textPosition to none.

```
vAxis:{
         baselineColor: '#fff',
         gridlineColor: '#fff',
         textPosition: 'none'
       }
```

Comment: You can also set the color to 'transparent'

Comment: @PatrikBeck try hAxis:{
         textPosition: 'none'
       }    for x axis

Answer (score 12):

With the current version of Google Charts, the following removes axis lines:

```
hAxis: {
  baselineColor: 'none',
  ticks: []
},
vAxis: {
  baselineColor: 'none',
  ticks: []
}
```

Comment: I spent a while trying to figure out why this wasn't working, only to realise that the baseline for the hAxis is a vertical line and the baseline for the vAxis is a horizontal line. So if you want to remove the horizontal black line you need to set the vAxis `baselineColor` and vice-versa.

Comment: This is perfect answer. Thanx a lot for help

Comment: @ChrisWheeler 's comment provided the missing link for me.  Thank you.